# Laravel 4: JSON Response is being outputted in the html body

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a Resourceful Controller and would like to add another route for my API response. But it seems that when I type in my browser localhost/mylaravel/api/updates it does appear that the output is not in the application/json content type. I viewed it in firebug and verified that the JSON are added in the html body wrapped with a <pre> tag. How do I resolve such issue?

routes.php

```
 Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {

        Route::get('updates', 'PluginsController@updatesNotification');

});

Route::resource('plugins', 'PluginsController');
```

PluginsController.php

```
class PluginsController extends BaseController {
public function index() { ... }
public function create() { ... }
...
...
...
public function updatesNotification() {
        return Response::json(array('name' => 'Steve', 'state' => 'CA'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's just how JSON that's sent as `application/json` gets rendered in Firefox. `Response::json` should be sending it correctly as `application/json`. In Firefox I can tell the difference based on the font. Try creating `test.html` and putting nothing but JSON in it and you'll see that it's in a regular font with no `<pre>` around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON <pre> tag is displayed in Firebug only.

You can direclty use the output object of Response::json()  to manipulate and render data.
```

It worked fine for me when i was returning AJAX response using Response::json() mehod  to plot graphs using Jqplot library.

```
My code is 

return View::make('jqplot::line')->with('data', Response::json($tdata));
```